# Sorting a List with type T

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of type `<T>` with bubble sort. Unfortunately I have issues with comparing objects with unknown type.

What I've tried so far:

```
public static void BubbleSort<T>(this List<T> array)
{
    for (int i = (array.Count - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) // issue here
            {
                var temp = array[j - 1];
                array[j - 1] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider having an `IComparer<T>` parameter as well... or use `Comparer<T>.Default`. I'd *strongly* consider renaming your parameter, given that a `List<T>` is not an array. (I assume this is for educational purposes only?)

Comment: @Sriram I'd assume he's learning how a bubble sort works.

Comment: @Carra Well I appreciate learning, but I'll use `List.Sort` rather than our own version unless there is a good reason to do so.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel i bet you come back here, if you need a method that says if you List<T> is sorted or not :)

Comment: I don't need a `BubbleSort` implementaion for that. I guess am not missing something? Am I?

Comment: If you want to make custom sort then the better way is to use **IComparable<T>** for enabling the comparing functionality to class and for filtering create new class with **IComparer** implementation  for custom filtering.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - never having written your own BubbleSort _is_ a very good reason to do it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Still I'd write my own version, but I'd hardly use it in production when .Net provides me one(unless it isn't performing well).

Comment: We can be sure about 2 things for this BubbleSort: 1) it won't go into any Production build and 2) it won't perform well.

Comment: In our school we had to write our own structures and algorithms first. Write a bubblesort, quick sort, merge sort... Write a linked list, hashset... Once you've written and tested it, just use the standard libraries. But at least you now know how a quicksort works and why you want to use it instead of a bubble sort.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't need to have anything other than the default comparison, you can use:

```
// TODO: Rename the parameter...
public static void BubbleSort<T>(this List<T> array)
{
    IComparer<T> comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    ...
    if (comparer.Compare(array[j - 1], array[j]) > 0)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or to allow custom comparisons:

```
public static void BubbleSort<T>(this List<T> array, IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    ...
    if (comparer.Compare(array[j - 1], array[j]) > 0)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or to restrict `T` to types which implement `IComparable<T>`:

```
public static void BubbleSort<T>(this List<T> array) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    ...
    if (array[j - 1].CompareTo(array[j]) > 0)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that adding the constraint on `T` here means that any *caller* needs to know that the type argument they use needs to implement `IComparable<T>`... it makes it safer at compile-time, at the cost of the constraint being propagated up the call chain. (One option would be to allow a constrained version without a comparer and an unconstrained version *with* a comparer.)

Answer (score 8):

No, you cannot compare 2 `T` values with `>`.

First you need to add a constraint on `T`:

```
public static void BubbleSort<T>(this List<T> array)
   where T : IComparable<T>
{
}
```

and then you can call

```
//if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) // issue here
if (array[j - 1].CompareTo(array[j]) > 0) // solved
```

Comment: +1 on having the extension method explicitly place a type constraint such that it is comparable.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to require `T` to implement the `IComparable` or `IComparable<T>` interface, as defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).